# How to test AngularJS $asyncValidators including a $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a jasmine test for AngularJS email availability checker, which uses Angular latest feature - $asyncValidators pipeline. Here is my directive:

```
au_helper.directive('recordAvailabilityValidator',
['$http', function ($http) {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            var apiUrl = attrs.recordAvailabilityValidator;
            var ownId = attrs.recordAvailabilityId;

            ngModel.$asyncValidators.unavailable = function(value) {
                return $http({method: 'GET', url: apiUrl, params: {v: value, id: ownId}});
            };

        }
    }
}]);
```

In my test I try to setup backend response like so:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'api/users/emailAvailable?v=test@email.com')
        .respond(400, {flash: 'not available'});
$scope.user = {email: null};
    var element = angular.element(
        '<form name="form">' +
        '<input ng-model="user.email" name="email" record-availability-validator="api/users/emailAvailable" />' +
        '</form>'
    );
    $compile(element)($scope);
    form = $scope.form;
```

and then test it:

```
it('should show an error if creating record with existing email', function () {
        form.email.$setViewValue('test@email.com');
        $scope.$digest();
        expect(form.email.$error.unavailable).toBeDefined();
    });
```

However, $error.unavailable is always undefined.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your $httpBackend for the call to actually happen

```
it('should show an error if creating record with existing email', function () {
    form.email.$setViewValue('test@email.com');
    $scope.$digest();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(form.email.$error.unavailable).toBeTruthy();
});
```